# Capturing a regex group nested/enclosed by special character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search for words that appear within tilde (`~`) sign borders.

```
 e.g. ~albert~ is a ~good~ boy.
```

I know that this is possible by using `~.+?~`,and it already works for me. But There are special cases when I need to match a nested tilde sentence.

```
 e.g. ~The ~spectacle~~ was ~broken~
```

In the example above, I have to capture 'The Spectacle', 'spectacle', and 'broken' separately. These will be translated either word-by-word or with accompanying article (An, The, whatever). The reason is that in my system:

```
1) 'The spectacle' requires a separate translation on a specific cases.
2) 'Spectacle' also needs translation on specific cases.
3) IF a tranlsation exist for The spectacle, we will use that, ELSE 
   we will use
```

Another example to explain this is:

```
 ~The ~spectacle~~ was ~borken~, but that was not the same ~spectacle~ 
  that was given to ~me~.
```

In the example above, I will have translation for:

```
 1) 'The spectacle' (because the translation case exists for 'The spectacle', otherwise I would've only translated spectacle on it's own)
 2) 'broken'
 3) 'spectacle'
 4) me
```

I am having trouble combining an expression which will make sure that this is captured in my regular expression. The one that I have managed to work with so far is '~.+?~'. But I know that with some form of lookahead or lookbehind, I can get this working. Could anyone help me on this?

The most important aspect in this is the regression-proofing, which will ensure that the existing stuff don't break. If I manage to get it right, I will post it.

N.B. If it helps, currently I will have instances where only one level of nesting will require decomposition. so ~The ~spectacle~~ will be deepest level (until i need more!!!!!)

Comment: I think the 2nd example should also yield `broken`.

Comment: Unless you can limit yourself to a fixed nesting depth, you need a regex engine capable of handling recursion. Which one are you using?

Comment: @stribizhev      you are right, updating the body now

Comment: @TimPietzcker      I am gonna be using it in Java. But I thought this may be a regex specific question, so didn't tag it with java.

Comment: All regex question need a language tag (see the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)). No recursion in Java regexes, sorry.

Comment: It is not a **regular language** and that should be resolved with a **parser** and not with a **Regular Expression** alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something like this a while ago, I haven't tested it much though:

```
(~(?(?=.*?~~.*?~).*?~.*?~.*?~|[^~]+?~))
```

or

```
(~(?(?=.*?~[A-Za-z]*?~.*?~).*?~.*?~.*?~|[^~]+?~))
```

## [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/xC5vI4/2)

Another alternative

```
(~(?:.*?~.*?~){0,2}.*?~)
                 ^^ change to max depth
```

which ever works best

To add more add a few extra sets of `.*?~` in the two places where you see a bunch.

## The main problem

If we allow unlimited nesting How would we know where it would end and begin? A clumsy diagram:

```
~This text could be nested ~ so could this~ and this~ this ~Also this~
|                          |              |_________|      |         |
|                          |_______________________________|         |
|____________________________________________________________________|
```

or:

```
~This text could be nested ~ so could this~ and this~ this ~Also this~
|                          |              |         |      |_________|
|                          |______________|         |
|___________________________________________________|
```

The compiler would have no idea which to choose

## For your sentence

```
~The ~spectacle~~ was ~broken~, but that was not the same ~spectacle~ that was given to ~me~.
|    |         ||_____|      |                            |         |
|    |         |_____________|                            |         |
|    |____________________________________________________|         |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

or:

```
~The ~spectacle~~ was ~broken~, but that was not the same ~spectacle~ that was given to ~me~.
|    |_________||     |______|                            |_________|                   |__|
|_______________|
```

## What should I do?

Use an alternating character (as @tbraun suggested) so the compiler knows where to start and end:

```
{This text can be {properly {nested}} without problems} because {the compiler {can {see {the}}} start and end points} easily. Or use a compiler:
```

*Note: I don't do Java much so some code might be incorrect*

```
import java.util.List;

String[] chars = myString.split('');
int depth = 0;
int lastMath = 0;
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 1) {
    if (chars[i] === '{') {
        depth += 1;
        if (depth === 1) {
            lastIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if (chars[i] === '}') {
        depth -= 1;
        if (depth === 0) {
            results.add(StringUtils.join(Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, lastIndex, i + 1), ''));
        }
        if (depth < 0) {
            // Balancing problem Handle an error
        }
    }
}
```

This uses [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Comment: From what I tested this doesn't work if you have 3 or more layers of tildes

Comment: @Voidpaw OP Said he'll only have one layer

Comment: He also specifically said "until I need more!!!!!", so we might as well try to fix the problem regardless of the amount of layers.

Comment: @tbraun I've mentioned you :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need something to differentiate start/finish patterns. I.e. `{}`

Than you can use pattern `\{[^{]*?\}` to exclude `{`:

```
{The {spectacle}} was {broken}
```

First iteration

```
{spectacle}
{broken}
```

Second iteration

```
{The spectacle}
```

Comment: why the downvote? other solution was updated after my post stating the real solution was to use alternate characters { } I shouldn't be punished for providing a real solution